# Laravel: Get current params in routes.php

Tags: php, laravel, navigation

I'm using the extension laravel-menu in my Laravel application.
This application contains multiple projects with multiple locations attached to each project.

Now I want to define a sidemenu where I can among other manage the locations.
The url of a project is

```
project/1
```

The url of the locations page of a project is

```
project/1/locations
```

How to setup this side menu in routes.php?

My routes.php code:

```
Route::resource('project', 'ProjectsController'));
Route::resource('project.locations', 'LocationsController');

    Menu::make('sidemenu-project', function($menu) {
        $menu->add('Locaties', array('route' => 'project.locations.index','{project?}'))->data('id',1); // this is not working

    });
```

This is outputting the url /project/%7Bproject%7D/locations

Answer (score 0):

Go to your terminal (Command Prompt) and run following command:

```
> php artisan routes
```

Then you'll see all the declared routes  with their `URL` and corresponding route name and `method name`.

Comment: Sorry, on closer inspection it didn't helped me. I thought is was working, but I added the menu script also in the controller action from where I retrieved the project id. But this menu will occur on multiple pages and I don't want to add the same menu in each controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very new to Laravel but the Routes page of documentation mentions you create a controller with parameters like this:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function($id) { ... });
```

could you therefore define your route as

```
Route::get('project/{id}/locations', function($id) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this issue due to misconfiguring the routes. To achieve the route structure that you want, you should put your `project/1/locations` route definition **above** the first one. Consider your routes.php to be:

```
 Route::resource('project/{project}/locations', ['as'=>'project.locations', 'uses'=> 'LocationsController']);
 Route::resource('project', 'ProjectsController'));
```

Comment: Makes sense, but I get an Array to string conversion error when I do this?

Comment: Had a glance at the menu package, and the docs state, that `->data()` is for sending metadata information. I don't think you are using it here as intended.

Comment: Have a look at the https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu#controller-actions. Dig it further ;)

Comment: Yes I know, but I cant get the current project id in routes.php. Otherwise I have to put this menu script in each controller action.

Comment: Put it in the __construct() method

Comment: That's possible, but i also mean multiple controllers. :p

Comment: Why to cope those too? Don't you have a BaseController that you extend? If you do, you can just call parent construct method in every of your controllers. That's simple.